# uikit framework - progress bar animation zero to value

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, getuikit

I want to animate the progress bar from 0 to value when user enter / load page.

I am working on the example here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u5c0oyL4/)

```
<progress id="js-progressbar" style="direction:rtl;" class="uk-progress" value="50" min="0" max="100"></progress>

   UIkit.util.ready(function () {


    var bar = document.getElementById('js-progressbar');

    var animate = setInterval(function () {

        bar.value += 10;

        if (bar.value >= bar.max) {
            clearInterval(animate);
        }

    }, 1000);


});
```

In this example, the bar animation progresses step by step.

can you help me?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to shorten the time and step value, so the animation is more fluid (see example), but to make it really animate, it is better to use 2 progress bars (one holder and one with specified width), where you animate the width which can be done by CSS and looks much better. This is how [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/progress/) animates progress bars

```js
UIkit.util.ready(function() {
  var bar = document.getElementById('js-progressbar');
  var animate = setInterval(function() {
    bar.value += 1;

    if (bar.value >= bar.max) {
      clearInterval(animate);
    }
  }, 5);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.42/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.42/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<progress id="js-progressbar" style="direction:rtl;" class="uk-progress" value="10" min="0" max="100"></progress>
```